# What does "via time stamping between sensors" mean?

Tags: terminology

I want to know how to understand the part *"via time stamping between sensors"* in the following sentence:

> The ZR300 supports Google Project Tango spec for feature tracking and synchronization via time stamping between sensors.

I know the sentence means ZR300 is very useful in the Google project Tango but I don't understand the detail of it.

Comment: What is a ZR300? Generally "supports x spec" means that they are using the standard specification defined by x, even if the projects are unrelated. Like "Firefox supports output to the Adobe PDF document format."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a technical than a language question. I'm not sure but I think you want to know what **time stamping** is.

a **timestamp** is a time record logged in a certain moment. It could include date also.

What I understand is the sensors of the Tango Kit record time when some event happen and synchronize between each other. Maybe to help the sensors capture motion or something.

You should understand that better as you are the one who is reading about it.

I hope this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. I think you are right!!! Now I got it. THANK YOU!!